# Firebase 'value' then 'child_changed' events optimization

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my SPA starts up I'd like to ask for a single event which gives me the state of a path in the database which represents a list. Something like:

```
let users;
const handler = (snap) => {};

firebase.ref('/foo').once('value')
  .then(snap => users = snap)
  .then(firebase.ref('/foo').on('child_changed', handler))
```

The goal being that I retrieve all the users immediately as part of a single network event. I then watch for any new child records and only get the new children when they come in (rather than the whole list).

Comment: What is the problem or question? How do you want to optimize this? Did you mean `.then(() => firebase.ref...)`? You probably also want `snap => users = snap.val()`.

Comment: i want to a 1 time fetch of the list and then only subscribe to child updates (versus the 'value' event which is inefficient for lists outside of initial loading)

Comment: Something similar is done in the [AngularFire2 `list` observable implementation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/4.0.0-rc.0/src/database/firebase_list_factory.ts#L103-L230). It's a little complicated, as the `child_added` events can occur synchronously in certain circumstances, but if you spend some time perusing the code, it should make sense.

Comment: @cartant Great, i'll have a look. I had looked in the Emberfire code and didn't see that but I'll see if I can grok the Angular code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use on "child_added" event. to fetch new user.

update:
To fetch old message first use on "value" event. In the callback function register listener for "child_added" and unlisten on "value". We are not using 'once' because when the chat is new and there are no messages 'once' will not be triggered. In order to get only new messages sort them using **orderByChild** method but you will need some kind of child like a timestamp of the message and then use last message's timestamp from previous array that you received from on "value". **startAt**(lastMessage.timestamp) should help

Comment: yes i want to use the more granular events like `child_added` but the point was i want _first_ get all records with the `value` event and then switch listening to to granular events without having `child_added` initially trigger an event for all the records which have already been brought back by the `value` event. this optimizes initial state hydration (via `value`) and then switches to granular events for state maintenance afterward.

Comment: **startAt** is a good suggestion; hadn't thought of that. Also as I contemplate it I guess the "value" event should just be listened too with a `once` so that it immediately disconnects.

Comment: updated the answer. explained why 'once' will not work, at least in current version of firebase.